# Can't get value from listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

**Bean Class**

```
 public partial class IPSFlightPath {            
        private string nameField;            
        private string sidField;            
        private int selectedField;}
```

**Main Class**

1.1.Set value for listbox

```
IPSFlightPath[] arrFlightPath = ipsChannel.paths;                           
foreach (IPSFlightPath flightPath in arrFlightPath)
{
  if (flightPath.selected != 0)
  {
  lbSelected.Items.Add(flightPath.name);
  }
}
```

1.2.Get value from listbox

```
string FP = lbSelected.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
```

It just set FP is name , didn't get selectedValue of object.
Example: row1 show nameField is 'FlightPath1' which contain sidField is '1'.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
lbSelected.Items.Add(new ListItem(flightPath.name, flightPath.sidField));
```